# E: Unable to locate package tlp

Tags: software-installation, apt

I an trying to install `tlp` as explained in the [website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) by addin `ppa` as follows in `Linux Mint 15`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

`sudo apt-get update`

produces

```
Hit http://panthema.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                               
Hit http://panthema.net precise Release                                        
Get:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                     
Hit http://panthema.net precise/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                       
Get:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia Release [18.5 kB]                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                           
Get:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main i386 Packages [23.5 kB]        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages          
Get:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream i386 Packages [9,237 B]    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Get:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import i386 Packages [40.1 kB]      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Ign http://panthema.net precise/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en             
Ign http://panthema.net precise/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US                                                                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                                                                                                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_US                                                                                           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                                                                                                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                                                                                              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US                                                                                   
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en_US                                                                                           
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/import Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia/upstream Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 91.6 kB in 20s (4,571 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

But when I try

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

it gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tlp
E: Unable to locate package tlp-rdw
```

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-tlp-raring.list` I have

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: *Raring* (Ubuntu 13.04) is no longer supported, so the packages for it have probably been dropped from the PPA. Try *Precise* (12.04, the current long-term support version) or *Saucy* (13.10, the current normal version) instead.

Comment: @n.st yup that seems to be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, its works for me :

1. Add new repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://repo.linrunner.de/debian wheezy main
   ```
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw`

Hope this will work for you.